# Where do image compression artifacts come from?

Tags: python, image, compression

Images that were scanned and in some way compressed often have specific artifacts around the text as the ones shown below:

[image]

[image]

I need to create text (right now I am using a python script), that is placed onto some background images and should have those exact artifacts. I don't really know how to create them, so until now I played around with just creating noisy grey maps and layering them over the image patch I need, which looks okay, but if possible it should be as close to the real artifacts as possible. Does anyone know how this usually happens or even better how I could create that in a simple script?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From the limited amount of experience with image compression that I have, I think if you compress an image by making it into a JPEG format then reconvert it back repeatedly you can get some desired artefacts.

A python script using PIL should be relatively simple but this is where my experience falters.

I'd recommend taking a look at the wikipedia for [compression artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact).